# How to delete different type of slice using only 1 methods

Tags: go, slice, type-assertion

I have 2 go functions like following

```
 func removeL2McEntry(a []api.L2McEntry, index int) []api.L2McEntry {
    a = append(a[:index], a[index+1:]...) 
    element
    return a[:len(a)]
 }

 func removeVlagBasedGroup(a []api.VlanPortBased, index int) []api.VlanPortBased {
    a = append(a[:index], a[index+1:]...) 
    return a[:len(a)]
 }
```

As you can see, both functions are doing the same work. But I need to separate them because the outputs and the inputs of the functions are different type.

I have tried:

```
func removeSlice(a interface{}, idx int) interface{} {
    switch v := a.(type) { 
    case []string:
        v = append(v[:idx], v[idx+1:]...) 
        fmt.Println("is ary", v)
        return v[:len(v)]
    case []int:
        v = append(v[:idx], v[idx+1:]...) 
        fmt.Println("is ary", v)
        return v[:len(v)]
    default:

    }
    return nil
}
```

But there is too many repetitive code in this way.
Is there any way to make it just one function and reduce the repetitive code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generics could solve this. Go does not have generics. You can search around for more info on that fact.

Comment: Your function replaces a single line of code, saving nothing, what is the point of making it a function at all?

Comment: Also, `a[:len(a)]` is unnecessary. For an array-to-slice conversion you could use `a[:]` to get the whole thing, but since it's already a slice, this does nothing; it is exactly equivalent to just `a` but with additional unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adrian noted, removing an element from a slice is one line of code, in general:

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1]...)
// or
a = a[:i+copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])]
```

It's not really worth writing a function for it, just use this code snippet where needed.

If you do need to create a function that can handle any slice types, it can be created using reflection. But when using it, you will have to use a type assertion on the result, as the function can only return a static type of `interface{}`. It will also be slower than using the above snippet on your concrete slice value!

The above remove steps can be "reproduced" using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. Slicing is the [`Value.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Slice) method, and the append operation is the [`reflect.AppendSlice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#AppendSlice) function.

This is how it could look like (types and bound checks omitted):

```
func remove(s interface{}, i int) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    return reflect.AppendSlice(v.Slice(0, i), v.Slice(i+1, v.Len())).Interface()
}
```

Testing it:

```
is := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
is = remove(is, 2).([]int)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", is)

ss := []string{"0", "1", "2", "3"}
ss = remove(ss, 2).([]string)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ss)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/11_J8u-xAOy)):

```
[]int{0, 1, 3}
[]string{"0", "1", "3"}
```

But again: I don't advise anyone to use this (although working) code, just remove the element directly with the original snippet.

Comment: Note that doing this using reflection is going to be slower than simple slice manipulation.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, it's worth noting it. I don't advise anyone to use this code, it's just here for "educational" purposes.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks your explanation and time, I do not have much experience in go. You explain this very precisely, thanks again.